# How to copy the parameters: program_id, program_num, pmt_pid, pcr_pid

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, udp

Tell me, please, how to copy the following parameters:

program_id, program_num, pmt_pid, pcr_pid

from the input broadcast to the output.

launch command: `ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -re  -fix_sub_duration -i 'srt://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx?passphrase=my_passphrase' -map 0 -map_metadata 0:p -c copy  -copyts -start_at_zero -f mpegts 'udp://239.0.0.7:1234?localaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&pkt_size=1316&ttl=32&buffer_size=10000000'`

Report:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'srt://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx?passphrase=my_passphrase':
   Duration: N/A, start: 14320.125411, bitrate: N/A
   Program 28
     metadata:
       service_name : My Service SD
       service_provider: My SP
     Stream #0:0[0xb4]: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, top first, left), 720x576 [SAR 64 :45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
     Stream #0:1[0xb5](RUS): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
     Stream #0:2[0x3ea]: Data: scte_35
     Stream #0:3[0xb8](rus,rus): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
[mpegts @ 0x55a92a179ae0] service 1 using PCR in pid=256, pcr_period=80ms
[mpegts @ 0x55a92a179ae0] muxrate VBR, sdt every 500 ms, pat/pmt every 100 ms
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://239.0.0.7:1234?localaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&pkt_size=1316&ttl=32&buffer_size=10000000':
   metadata:
     service_name : My Service SD
     service_provider: My SP
     encoder : Lavf58.45.100
     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, top first, left), 720x576 (0x0) [SAR 64 :45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
     Stream #0:1(RUS): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
     Stream #0:2: Data: scte_35
     Stream #0:3(rus,rus): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
   Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
   Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
```

service_name and service_provider
are copied from the incoming to the outgoing, and program_id, etc. - no

Report `ffprobe -show_programs`:

Incoming:

```
[PROGRAM]
program_id=28
program_num=28
nb_streams=4
pmt_pid=182
pcr_pid=180
start_pts=7879391078
start_time=7879.391078
end_pts=N/A
end_time=N/A
TAG:service_name=My Service SD
TAG:service_provider=My SP
```

Outgoing:

```
[PROGRAM]
program_id=1
program_num=1
nb_streams=4
pmt_pid=4096
pcr_pid=256
start_pts=42423669722
start_time=42423.669722
end_pts=N/A
end_time=N/A
TAG:service_name=My Service SD
TAG:service_provider=My SP
```